# Proper way to concatenate a hyperlink into string

Tags: asp.net

What would be the best way to properly concatenate string with an url inside? Can it be okay with this?

```
String.Format("This is the link: <a href={0}>{1}</a>", somevalue1, somevalue2)
```

Or it probably leaves open door for injection attacks?

So how would I insert a hyperlink within a string?

I guess I could do with HyperLink class, but then is there any property that returns html code for the class object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below uses [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink_methods%28VS.71%29.aspx) and should work.  However, consider whether you really need an intermediate string in the first place.

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;

HyperLink link = new HyperLink(){NavigateUrl="http://stackoverflow.com", Text = "StackOverflow"};
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
link.RenderControl(htw);
sw.Close();
String rendered = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: +1 for explaining how to get the HTML from the `HyperLink` control.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid HTML injection, you would do this:

```
String.Format("This is the link: <a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>",
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(somevalue1), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(somevalue2))
```

Do not use `UrlEncode` for HTML values (attributes and text), because it will just look garbled. `UrlEncode` is for query string values, i.e. `page.aspx?param=value+that+has+been+encoded`

Answer (score 1):

You missed the quotes:

```
String.Format("This is the link: <a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", somevalue1, somevalue2)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/encoding_forms.aspx) article talks about how to accomplish this in a secure way using [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: I don't believe that's what he's looking for. He's setting the `href` attribute and the text of the anchor. He's not building a URL that needs to have its query string values encoded.

Comment: He asked about possible security concerns so I assumed he was taking input from users

Answer (score 0):

If you set what you get from your client to the link'!s href, it always causes a backdoor for injection attacks.

You should use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) to encode querystrings of your links, to get secure links.